# Setting Default SAVE Locations in flex3 web application

Tags: apache-flex

In flex 3 web application how to set default save location for images?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [FileReference documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/FileReference.html):

> The FileReference and FileReferenceList classes do not let you set the default file location for the dialog box that the browse() or download() methods generate. The default location shown in the dialog box is the most recently browsed folder, if that location can be determined, or the desktop. The classes do not allow you to read from or write to the transferred file. They do not allow the SWF file that initiated the upload or download to access the uploaded or downloaded file or the file's location on the user's disk.

If you're using AIR, you have more control using the [File](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/filesystem/File.html) class.